# Can I change the MCU sleeping mode programmatically on FreeRTOS?

Tags: embedded, freertos

I am a new been on FreeRTOS and working on a board that uses the

Cortex-M4 Processor and the FreeRTOS

"FreeRTOS V7.4.2 - Copyright (C) 2013 Real Time Engineers Ltd."

Can I change the MCU mode programmatically or through a debugger?

I want to make sure the MCU is NOT in sleeping mode. I looked at this thread but did not help much.

[Entering sleep mode on arm cortex m4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055888/entering-sleep-mode-on-arm-cortex-m4)

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically set the processor to enter sleep mode it will not be in sleep mode. You shouldn't have to do anything. You are also using quite an old version of FreeRTOS, I would recommend downloading 9.0.0.

See http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABHHGEB.html

for info on how to enter sleep mode.